# Convert Timestamp value to same milliseconds value irrespective of which timezone you access it from

Tags: java-8, timezone

We have a Oracle database where the Timestamp is stored in MDT. I'm want to fetch this value and convert it to long (milliseconds) and this long value is then converted on the UI and shown.

I want the value of milliseconds to be same irrespective of whichever timezone it is being accessed from.

For ex: If the Timestamp stored in DB is **20-10-22 9:46:27.000000000 AM ** (in MDT timezone) then i want this to be converted to long and when this long is parsed on UI it should show  **20-10-22 9:46:27 ** (same date and time) irrespective of whichever timezone the UI is accessed from.

Can someone suggest me on how to go about it?

I've tried conversions and parsing suggested on other posts but the long value generated will be different when tried from different timezone

Comment: can u show the code ?

Comment: @RyuzakiL
Timestamp mdtTimestamp = Timestamp.valueOf("2020-10-22 09:46:27.000000000");
        long millisecondsValue = mdtTimestamp.getTime();
        System.out.println(millisecondsValue);

In this code the output is 1603381587000 which when converted back to date will be Thursday, October 22, 2020 9:16:27 PM

Comment: Are you trying to convert this epoch value to date at client side? Can you please provide the code which you are using for this conversion at UI?

Comment: @GD07 From UI it is proper and when i check the logs i can see that the value sent from the server itself is wrong